# git: can pull but can't push

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have a weird behavior, because I can pull but i can't push.

I have a ssh key and everytime I try to pull or push it asks me for a passphrase.

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/b.rcb/.ssh/id_rsa':
Hi ricardochampa! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide
 shell access.


$ git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/b.rcb/.ssh/id_rsa':
Already up-to-date.


$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/b.rcb/.ssh/id_rsa':
ERROR: Permission to rchampa/ParsersSubasta.git denied to ricardochampa.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm using windows.

Comment: 1. The passphrase is for your key file. You don't have to set it up and you can remove it from the key; it's easy to Google. 2. Other than that: Is it your repo you try to push to? What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: @musiKk Ya but the thing is I dont want to remove it. And yes I checked my remotes urls and all are fine. As I said I can pull wihtout problems. The problem occurs only when I try to push.

Comment: I just asked because push and pull URLs can be different. If that's all good, I'm not sure what the problem could be, sorry.

Comment: Do you have write access to the remote repository?

Comment: @Ricardo What happens once you run the `git config --global push.default simple` command as git asks you to? Do you still get the error?

Comment: @mu無 Yes, still getting error.

Comment: @rmorrin Yes, I have uploaded my ssh key to my github account. Probably I will repeat the ssh generation key.